# how to load thumbnail from MediaStreamSource

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm trying to get a thumbnail from a `MediaStreamSource` and show it in an `Image` control using this code:

```
try
{
    var img = new BitmapImage();
    img.SetSource(await mss.Thumbnail.OpenReadAsync());
    imgThumbnail.ImageSource = img;
    mediaElement.PosterSource = img;
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
    Output("poster exception: "+ ex.Message); 
}
```

but I'm getting an exception:

> poster exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show in your code where (or how) you declare `imgThumbnail`, `mss` and `mediaElement`.

Answer (score 0):

you'd have to share a bit more about your code to get more help on this one.

I'm guessing that the Thumbnail property is null, because you either haven't initialized your stream source correctly, or there is no album or video art available for the given stream. Check out the sample here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/MediaStreamSource-media-dfd55dff for more help.